# How to manualy spawn a client in a specific tag in Awesome?

Tags: linux, shell-script, awesome-wm

I already have automatic tag assignation for clients using rules, but sometimes I need to spawn a client in a specific tag.

For example, I usualy want my browser (dwb) in tag 2 using the following rule:

```
awful.rules.rules = {
    [...]
    { rule = { class = "Dwb" }, properties = { tag = tags[1][2] } },
}
```

But when spawning a browser for a debug session, I want it to spawn in another tag (along with my IDE) let's say tag 3.

How can I launch a program from the command line so that its client(s) will spawn in a tag specified as a parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function and use it through the awesome client tool.

First, create a function and add it to your rc.lua file :

```
function spawn(command, class, tag, test)
local test = test or "class"
local callback
callback = function(c)
    if test == "class" then
        if c.class == class then
            awful.client.movetotag(tag, c)
            client.disconnect_signal("manage", callback)
        end
    elseif test == "instance" then
        if c.instance == class then
            awful.client.movetotag(tag, c)
            client.disconnect_signal("manage", callback)
        end
    elseif test == "name" then
           if string.match(c.name, class) then
               awful.client.movetotag(tag, c)
            client.disconnect_signal("manage", callback)
        end
    end
end
client.connect_signal("manage", callback)
awful.util.spawn_with_shell(command)
end
```

Then, restart your awesome session (generally through Ctrl+Super+r).

Then, as if you were writing a rule, choose the way to identify the client (window) to move. You can do it by class, by instance or by name. Use `xprop` to get informations on windows, also see this [FAQ](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#How_to_find_window.27s_class_and_other_identifiers.3F).

Finally, create a simple bash script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat <<EOF | awesome-client
spawn("/usr/bin/firefox", "Firefox", tags[1][1], "class")
EOF
```

You can add as many spawn action you want. I have wrotten multiple startup scripts that launch all programs I need depending on the task I intend to work on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Changing the callback is indeed quite a nice idea. I'll see if it solves my problem, especially for hard to identify clients and let you know

Comment: Very good solution, except for the client flashing on current screen; but that's not different from standard rules, thanks!

Comment: @mperrin: Thanks, I have an additional question: is it possible to differentiate between different instances of the same program? e.g. I would like different instances of google-chrome (with different profiles) to spawn on different tags. This method always matches the firs occurance (I think).

Comment: Ok, after a bit of searching: the client also has a pid, so I could remember that somwhere and test against that, or if the client list is ordered (which it seems to be, I could just pass an index/offset/counter, so I keep matching until the (hopefully) right client instance is reached. Might post another answer if I get it to work.